# Using XSL for-each-group

Tags: xml, xslt

I will try to make it as clear as possible. I have an XML that has inside a structure that follows:

```
<NetworkData>
  <NameOfSection1>
    <ChangeHistory>
      <ChangeHistoryItem>
        <Date>2012-06-04</Date>
        <Description>Add the USIM/SIM header</Description>
      </ChangeHistoryItem>
    </ChangeHistory>
  </NameOfSection1>
  <NameOfSection2>
    <ChangeHistory>
      <ChangeHistoryItem>
        <Date>2014-01-17</Date>
        <Description>Not changed</Description>
      </ChangeHistoryItem>
      <ChangeHistoryItem>
        <Date>2014-01-17</Date>
        <Description>Not changed</Description>
      </ChangeHistoryItem>
      <ChangeHistoryItem>
        <Date>2014-01-17</Date>
        <Description>Not changed</Description>
      </ChangeHistoryItem>
    </ChangeHistory>
  </NameOfSection2>
</NetworkData>
```

I want to create a table in XSL that contains all `ChangeHistoryItems` from all sections, ordered by date. In the end I want to generate a PDF file through Apache FOP.

I read about `for-each-group` but I don't know how should I use it, I'm a beginner in XSL/XML. Can you help? Many thanks.

Comment: Hi, I did my answer for HTML table, becouse output was not specified before edit. :)

Comment: `for-each-group` will not help you very much; it does not seem as if you wanted to group your data.

Comment: xsl:for-each-group is used when you need to add a hierarchic layer to your structure. Here you need to remove a layer, which is much eaier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Change history</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Date</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Description</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="//ChangeHistoryItem">
       <xsl:sort select="Date"/>
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Date"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="Description"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Here is description:**

```
<xsl:for-each select="//ChangeHistoryItem"> - all changeHistoryItem in any level
<xsl:sort select="Date"/> - Sort by elem date.
```

Comment: Thanks Jaroslav, I will try your code and send you a feedback asap.

Comment: I tried the code and it worked like a charm. Thank you once again Jaroslav, I accepted your answer.